# ASP.NET - Using generic handles to handle login

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been doing some research on secure login in asp.net and most of the posts I've read use already provided login controls. I wanted to use regular textboxes for username and password and use ajax to pass this data to a generic handled (Login.ashx for example) and then  log the user in without having to reload. Is this method secure and if not, what are it's vulnerability. The second option would be passing this data to a Login.aspx page and then redirecting to where i came from. Same question about security applies to this option too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do that and there are a lot of tutorials how to do it. However there is prebuilt way to do this. There is authentication service that can be deployed with Forms Authentication and it can be used to login users via AJAX. More information [here](https://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/tutorials/UsingFormsAuthenticationTutorial.aspx). Note that you can ignore the MS AJAX library, you just have to find the URL and craft the appropriate request. If I recall correctly the request is very simple, something along the lines of a json object with username and password.

Otherwise your method is in general secure if you do it right. You can still use Forms Authentication (or ASP.NET Identity) to login the user and I would recommend you do so. You should also make sure that your login handler is accessible to unauthorized users.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use SQL Parameters on the server to prevent SQL-injection and you have HTTPS enabled, it's going to be more or less safe.

However when you create a new ASP.NET project with Visual Studio - given that you have the latest Visual Studio updates and the ASP.NET updates installed - you can choose a SPA (Single Page Application) project. There you can see how microsoft implements such a scenario as a reference design.